# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated shifts view down

Tags: iphone

I'm using dismissModalViewControllerAnimated to dismiss my MFMailComposeViewController. The problem I'm having is that the view behind the mail view gets shifted down a bit when it comes back into view.

I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated I grab my view's frame and set the origin back to (0,0)

It works but this seems silly to have to do so if anyone comes up with a better answer I'll accept it or if I figure something better out I'll edit this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

I found out that it was caused by the way I initially sized the view of the parent of the modal viewcontroller.

I was using `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`

This is now what is working for me:

```
// loadView method of the parent of the modal view controller
- (void)loadView {
  CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
  self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
  [self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
  // Below is the actual code with the content of the view
  [...]
}
```