# UIPickerView Shifts When Loaded

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView that shifts vertical each time i load it. I have a feedback button on a toolbar on the bottom of this view as well. Of course, if i press this button i am taken to the email interface view to leave feedback. and, when i return to the UIPickerView, after leaving or cancelling feedback, the page shift is corrected. Any suggestions on why this shift is occurring in the first place? Any suggestions on how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question a while back and just noticed it has a new solution. Haven't had a chance to try it out but maybe it will help you.

[dismissModalViewControllerAnimated shifts view down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944614/dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated-shifts-view-down)